# page loading icon from css not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have css file like this

```
    .mask {
        display: none;
    }

    #mask.loading {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1000;
            background-image: url('/icon.gif')
            background-position: center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
    table.loading {
            opacity: .5;
}
```

And I want to show icon until table loads so I'm calling it like

```
$('#tableDisplay,#mask').addClass('loading');
$('#tableDisplay,#mask').removeClass('loading');
```

And in my html I added as

```
<div id="mask"></div>
<table id="tableDisplay">
</table>
```

And when I load page I can see table opaque but I do not see icon and my icon file is in same dir as css file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your use of:

```
background-image: url('/icon.gif')
```

The `slash` is telling it to look in the web-root for the icon ...  Remove the slash or give the full path IE

```
background-image: url('icon.gif')

background-image: url('/your/path/to/css/icon.gif')
```

This should also be apparent when you look in your console and see the `404` for the icon, you'll see the directory that the CSS file is "trying" to find `icon.gif` in

Answer (score 1):

Your first CSS rule has a class selector but it should be an ID:

```
#mask {  /* instead of .mask */
    display: none;
}
```

And your icon URL contains a slash which shouldn't be there if the icon is in the same directory:

```
background-image: url('icon.gif');
```